# Checking same object exists in 2 different buckets with boto3

Tags: boto3

I want to check if an object is present in a different bucket vs source. Source bucket might have same key with different versions so please find that I dont want to check if key exists but if the version is the same. I tried to do that looking at LastModified parameter but it seems they will always be different as this is changed when the object is copied.

Answer (score 2):

If you call [head_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) on the object in both buckets, you will be able to compare the `ETag` value in the reponses. The `ETag` value is the MD5 hash of the object. If both objects have the same `ETag` then they are identical files.

Comment: Have to be careful about the ETag. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html#checking-object-integrity-etag-and-md5) write 'object has an ETag that is not an MD5 digest of its object data." when encryption is used. So if one bucket has encryption, second not, ETags will not much for same objects.